# Nested if then statements in a for or while loop

Tags: bash

Im fairly new to bash so please take it easy if my code looks nasty or incorrect.

Im trying to make a script right now that will ping a hostname, and if that hostname doesn't respond it will grab the IP of the hostname and try that also. Might seem pointless but I have my reasons.

The issue I am having is my script is not recognizing "done" at the end of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#while read hostname; do
for hostname in $(cat host.txt); do
ping -c1 $hostname 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
SUCCESS=$?
if [ $SUCCESS -eq 0 ]
        then
        echo "$hostname has replied"
else#[ $SUCCESS -ne 0 ]
        echo "Hostname didn't reply, trying IP"
        ip=`cat /etc/hosts | grep $hostname | awk '{print $1}' `
        ping -c1 $ip 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
        SUCCESS=$?
                if [ $SUCCESS -eq 0 ]
                        then
                        echo "$ip has replied"
                        echo "------------------------------"
                else
                        echo "$ip didn't reply"
                        echo "------------------------------"
                fi
done
```

Comment: You forgot a `fi` to close your outer `if` block.  (Protip: Cleaning up your indentation can help make it easier to spot errors like this.)

Comment: Dump this code in [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) It will point out your unclosed `if` and the lack of a space in front of your comment in your `else` clause as well as any other problems with the script.

Comment: Omg..... Thank you. -.- I knew it was something stupid simple. And thanks for the tip! Thats definitely something I hae to practice

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted the code, indenting it in a more standard and common way. I also added a few comments that may help people learn the basics, like @Root_ was 4 years ago. You may check it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# I just used an editor that can do formatting of code.
# I asked it to reindent all lines within my settings.
# There are several programs to do this. I used vim.

for hostname in $(cat host.txt); do

    ping -c1 $hostname 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    SUCCESS=$?

    # ping ended successfully?
    if [ $SUCCESS -eq 0 ] then
        echo "$hostname has replied"
    else
        echo "Hostname didn't reply, trying IP"

        ip=`cat /etc/hosts | grep $hostname | awk '{print $1}' `

        ping -c1 $ip 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
        SUCCESS=$?

        # ping ended successfully?
        if [ $SUCCESS -eq 0 ] then
            echo "$ip has replied"
            echo "------------------------------"
        else
            echo "$ip didn't reply"
            echo "------------------------------"
        fi
    fi
    # You missed this last "fi". With good indentation,
    # we see it easily. And with an editor that is done
    # for developers, it may even point us a place to
    # look for errors. In this case, the "done" was
    # written in red, which helped me asking 2 questions:
    # 1. Is this done in the right place? Where is its
    # corresponding "do"? (it is on on line 7 now)
    # 2. So, if the done is correct, what else is wrong?
    # Then, for the indentation I did, it was easy to see
    # the 'if' on line 13 did not have a 'fi'.
done
```